# Rails 5 passes wrong argument into has_many :through scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose we have the following (albeit complicated) setup:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :homes, inverse_of: :company
  has_many :item_company_items, class_name: 'CompanyItem', inverse_of: :item_company, foreign_key: :item_company_id
  has_many :home_company_items, class_name: 'CompanyItem', inverse_of: :home_company, foreign_key: :home_company_id
  has_many :replacement_items, through: :item_company_items, source: :replacement_items, inverse_of: :responsible_company
end

class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :homes
  has_many :company_items, through: :company, source: :home_company_items, inverse_of: :homes
  has_many :replacement_items, inverse_of: :home
end

class CompanyItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, inverse_of: :company_items
  belongs_to :item_company, class_name: 'Company', inverse_of: :item_company_items, foreign_key: :item_company_id
  belongs_to :home_company, class_name: 'Company', inverse_of: :home_company_items, foreign_key: :home_company_id
  has_many :homes, through: :home_company, source: :homes, inverse_of: :company_items
  has_many :replacement_items, -> company_item {
    where item_id: company_item.item_id
  }, through: :homes, source: :replacement_items, inverse_of: :company_item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replacement_items, inverse_of: :item
  has_many :company_items, inverse_of: :item
end

class ReplacementItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, inverse_of: :replacement_items
  belongs_to :home, inverse_of: :replacement_items
  has_one :company_item, -> rep { where item_id: rep.item_id }, through: :home, source: :company_items, inverse_of: :replacement_items
  has_one :responsible_company, through: :company_item, source: :item_company, inverse_of: :replacement_items
end
```

So, in effect, `Item`s have many `CompanyItem`s which represent the `Company` that is responsible (`CompanyItem#item_company`) for `ReplacementItem`s belonging to that `Item` when the `ReplacementItem` is for a `Home` belonging to the `Company` specified by the `CompanyItem` (`CompanyItem#home_company`).

Very circuitous, but it's exactly what we need.

Now, as we can see, on the `ReplacementItem` model, the `has_one :company_item, through: :home` relationship uses a scope to select the specific `CompanyItem` belonging to the `home` that matches the `item_id`. This makes sense sence just doing `replacement_item.home.company_items` would give us all of `homes` company items, when we really just need the one that matches the given `ReplacementItem`. Calling the `ReplacementItem#company_item` method works flawlessly and gives us exactly what we want.

Likewise, the `CompanyItem` model has `has_many :replacement_items, through: :homes`, using the exact same scope to get just the replacement items that match the given `CompanyItem`. In this instance, however, we get an error when calling `CompanyItem#replacement_items`:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `item_id' for #<Company id: 2>
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:434:in `method_missing'
    bug.rb:59:in `block in <class:CompanyItem>'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:161:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:161:in `eval_scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:139:in `block in add_constraints'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:138:in `each'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:138:in `add_constraints'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:28:in `scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:5:in `scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:97:in `association_scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:327:in `scope'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:36:in `initialize'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:101:in `new'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:101:in `create'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:46:in `reader'
    /Users/cbankester/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/rails-bf5876af099f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:111:in `replacement_items'
    bug.rb:85:in `test_hmt_with_conditions'
```

This looks like a Rails bug to me. There's absolutely no way a `Company` object should be passed in to the `has_many :replacement_items` scope defined on the `CompanyItem` model. Before bugging the Rails team, though, I am hoping someone here has seen a similar problem or can point out the fault in my code.

See my gist here for a runnable, failing test: https://gist.github.com/cmbankester/64ef4eb125bf90dbe0274fab8e5427f1

Comment: Were you trying to report this to the Rails devs, or were you looking to see if you had missed something instead?  Looks like a bug report to me.

Comment: @Makoto Just looking to see if I had missed something. It's very possible that there's something that's just logically incorrect with the data flow that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: if youre going to submit a ticket to rails, you need to package your code into a reproducible executable. This would involve writing test cases, which might help you solve your problem anyway.